# Ternary operator in the middle of a statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a string where part of the string depends on whether the variable `json[i].has_dishwasher` contains a value. If it contains a value, `class="selected"` will be added to the html string. To make my code shorter (I actually have a long series of the code shown below), i am planning to use the ternary `if` operator.

**Problem:** The way I used the ternary `if` conditional statement is not valid Javascript. How can I make this valid?

**Javascript Code**

```
html = '<div class="amenities"' + (json[i].has_dishwasher ? +'class="selected"'+) \
+ '>Dishwasher' +  json[i].has_dishwasher + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "tri" part of the ternary, and it should return *just* the strings, not include the concatenation (`+`) operators.

```
... + (json[i].has_dishwasher ? 'class="selected"' : '') + ...
```

But that isn't really what you want either; that would leave you with two separate "class" attributes. I'd probably create the "class" attribute's value apart from the creation of the HTML string:

```
var classVal = "amenities" + (json[i].has_dishwasher ? " selected" : "");
```

Or just do it in a conditional and keep it clean.

```
var classVal = "amenities";
if (json[i].has_dishwasher) classVal += " selected";

html = '<div class="' + classVal + '>Dishwasher' 
     + json[i].has_dishwasher + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = '<div class="amenities"' + (json[i].has_dishwasher ? ' class="selected"' : '') + '>Dishwasher' +  json [i].has_dishwasher + '</div>';
```